# Как достигается согласованность в СУБД

Tags: база-данных

Как вообще достигается согласованность между СУБД, к примеру первая БД отправляет запрос второй что все готово я комичу если ты комитишь, второая БД говорит я комичу, первая БД говорит я закомитил, а второй это сообщение может же не получить, где гарантия что вторая БД получит сообщение, возможно все не так как я описал, мне интересно как вообще там реализуется согласованность

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID